# Struggling to select a value from another table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im currently constructing a database using PHP, HTML and MySQL.

I have an events table. `Event_id` is the primary key. When someone registers for an event they input their `student_id` and they also select an event from a dropbox that pulls the events from my events table. I have an `event_registration` table which records all entries into this form. I have `event_id` in my `event_registration` table and I'm trying to make it so that when someone selects a certain event, that event's id automatically goes into the `event_registration` table. My PHP code at present is this:

```html
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$sql = "select event_id from events where title LIKE $title";
$db->select_db($database);
$event_id = $db->query($sql);



$q  = "INSERT INTO event_registration (";
$q .= "student_id, event_id, title";
$q .= ") VALUES (";
$q .= "'$student_id', '$event_id', '$title')";

$result = $db->query($q);
```

The `student_id`, `title`, and `registraion_id` (auto- increment) are inserting fine, but `event_id` is always showing up as `0`, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```html
  <td style="width: 176px; height: 23px">Event Title</td>
  <td style="height: 23px"><select name="title" style="width: 124px">
  <?php 
  include ("detail.php"); 
  $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT title FROM events");
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
  ?>
  <option><?php echo  ($row['title']); ?></option>";
  
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select></td>
```

my dropdown code

Comment: You should really consider [using prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). As it is, you code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, you do not seem to check for errors, otherwise an expression like `title LIKE $title` (without single quotes around `$title`) would raise an error if `$title` is a string.

Comment: Because `$db->query($sql)` returns not what you expect.

Comment: I'm still very much a beginner to web design and I'm just trying to get it running before adding error checking, thanks though

Comment: @u_mulder so i need to change my select statement?

Comment: A recommendation, I'm guessing you have the title as the value on the select menu which is not a good idea, instead put the event_id directly as values on the select and show the title as the text on the dropdown, that way you won't have to do that extra query and also use the **LIKE** option. If you can, add the code where you're constructing the dropdown menu. Now, why is this code failing? I'd check to see if i'm actually getting a number on $event_id, do a var_dump($event_id) after the first query to see what you're getting.

Comment: This is my code for the dropdown

<?php 
   include ("detail.php"); 
   $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT title FROM events");
   while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
   ?>
   <option><?php echo  ($row['title']); ?></option>";
   
   <?php
   }
   ?>
i'm not sure how well it will format in a comment, how can i change this to be event id but show the title? thanks alot

Comment: To add to what GMB said, **LIKE** is usally added when trying to match things that are like others but not exactly with for example `LIKE '$prefix%'`, but in your case if hte user is getting the title from your menu and it's supossed to be the exact title, you could simply do WHERE title = '$title'. I still thing you could avoid that query by improving the dropdown.

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there instead, but in the meantime I'll add an answer with a possible fix by changing the menu.

Comment: I tried where title = '$title' and i got nothing unfortunately

Comment: Yes, the problem must be on the `$event_id = $db->query($sql)` because you're expecting a number but you're missing a step, you need to fetch the result you're looking for.

Comment: Ok your last comment makes a lot of sense i think i can get it

Comment: Good, I added an answer trying to fix problem by fetching, but really consider my recommendation of building the dropdown directly  with the id. When you have ids, you're better off using them than trying to match some text, try to keep the use of  **LIKE** for things like searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you seem to be having is:

```
$event_id = $db->query($sql);
```

Probably doesn't give you the number you're expecting right away, instead you need to fetch like this:

```
$result= $db->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
$event_id = $result['event_id'];
```

However, based on your comment, you're constructing your dropdown with this:

```
<?php 
    include ("detail.php"); 

    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "title FROM events"); 

    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){ 

?> 

<option><?php echo ($row['title']); ?></option> 

<?php } ?>
```

You can do this instead:

```
<?php 
    include ("detail.php"); 

    $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT event_id,title FROM events"); 

    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){ 

?> 

<option value="<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>"><?php echo ($row['title']); ?></option>"; 

<?php } ?>
```

Notice how I'm also adding event_id on the select caluse. WIth this the users will see the title as expected, but you'll get the id directly with POST like this:

```
$event_id = $_POST['event_id'];
```

You **DO** have to change the **name** of the select dropdown to event_id instead of title like this:

```
<select name="event_id">
```

Comment: thanks so much your first solution worked perfect, in the long term would it be better to change the dropdown?

Comment: I wouldn't say long term but right now. It's good that you figured out why it was failing but save those changes and now try to change the dropdown instead. The thing is, imagine you have multiple events, eventually you could have two events with the same title, but ids are unique so you shouldn't rely on the title to select the one you want. Give it a try with the code above, it shoulnd't be too dificult.

Comment: Yes ok that makes sense, ill make a backup and give it a try

Comment: Okay, I'll be around for a while. The steps would be (1) Change the name of the html select from **title** to **event_id** (2) On the query before you create the dropdown add **event_id,** to the fields you're getting (3) Add the **value** property on the options with the **event_id** (4) Remove the three lines for the query you were making with the LIKE (5) Create the variable event_id with  **$_POST['event_id']**